# Find $e^{xA}$ by definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

$A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

I have to find $e^{xA}$ **by definition**.

$A^1 =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$,$A^2 =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$,$A^3 =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$...

Then, $A^n =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2n & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$ for odd $n$

, $A^n =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2n & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ for even $n$

For odd $n$:

$e^{xA}=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & e^x \\
    0 & e^x & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2xe^x & e^x & 0 \\
    e^x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

For even $n$:

$e^{xA}=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    e^x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & e^x & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2xe^x & e^x & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & e^x \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

Is it correct ?

How can I find the general $e^{xA}$?  Is it the sum of both ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean "for odd $n$" and "for even $n$" in the bottom matrices that don't have $n$ appear anywhere? You will need to use both the odd and even terms in the infinite sum definition of $e^{xA}$ to get a single answer.

Comment: When $n$ is an odd number then I get a specific matrix form , and when n is an even number I get other matrix form. "You will need to use both the odd and even terms in the infinite sum definition of exA to get a single answer." - I know , but I am really stuck how to do it

Comment: To do $\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n$ you can do $\sum_{k=0}^\infty S_{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty S_{2k+1}$

Comment: When you compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^nA^n}{n!}$, you will need to, for certain entries, split this sum into even and odd terms: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}A^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n + 1}A^{2n + 1}}{(2n + 1)!}$. You might find it helpful to recall that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \cosh x$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n + 1}}{(2n + 1)!} = \sinh x$.

Answer (score 2):

You've done well, but you stumbled a little at the last hurdle. Consider the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray}e^{xA} & = & \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n A^n}{n!} \\
& = & \sum_{n \text{ even}} \frac{x^n A^n}{n!} + \sum_{n \text{ odd}} \frac{x^n A^n}{n!} \\
& = & \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k} A^{2k}}{(2k)!} + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1} A^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
\end{eqnarray}$$

What you did was nearer to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k A^{2k}}{k!}$ for the even terms and similarly for the odd terms, but notice that this doesn't line up at all.

I won't give the final answer, but as mentioned in the comments the sum of the even terms of the expansion of $e^x$ gives you $\cosh x$ and the sum of the odd terms gives you $\sinh x$, which should be enough for you to get a final answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is odd, then$$(xA)^n=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&x^n\\0&x^n&0&0\\0&2nx^n&x^n&0\\x^n&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and, if $n$ is even, then$$(xA)^n=\begin{bmatrix}x^n&0&0&0\\0&x^n&0&0\\0&2nx^n&x^n&0\\0&0&0&x^n\end{bmatrix}.$$Therefore, if $e^{xA}=B=(b_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant4}$, then:

- $b_{11}=b_{44}=1+\frac1{2!}x^2+\frac1{4!}x^4+\cdots=\cosh(x)$;
- $b_{12}=b_{13}=b_{21}=b_{23}=b_{24}=b_{31}=b_{34}=b_{42}=b_{43}=0$;
- $b_{14}=b_{41}=x+\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{5!}x^5+\cdots=\sinh(x)$;
- $b_{22}=b_{33}=e^x$;
- $b_{32}=2x+\frac4{2!}x^2+\frac6{3!}x^3+\cdots=2x\left(1+x+\frac1{2!}x^2+\frac1{3!}x^3+\cdots\right)=2xe^x$.

In other words,$$e^{xA}=\begin{bmatrix}\cosh(x)&0&0&\sinh(x)\\0&e^x&0&0\\0&2xe^x&e^x&0\\\sinh(x)&0&0&\cosh(x)\end{bmatrix}.$$